# fix xticks starting from 1 in python with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, xticks

I am trying to put xticks in a plt figure. However, ticks start from 0 while I want to start from 1 how can I fix this? I tried this (based on a similar question I found) but still nothing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y= np.array([[1], [2], [0.5], [1.4],[5], [4], [3.5], [1.2]])
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(y, marker="o")
x_ticks = np.arange(1, len(y), 5)
plt.xticks(x_ticks)
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a `x` array to be used to draw the plot:

```
x = np.arange(1, len(y) + 1, 1)
```

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y= np.array([[1], [2], [0.5], [1.4],[5], [4], [3.5], [1.2]])
x = np.arange(1, len(y) + 1, 1)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y, marker="o")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: ok thanks a lot!